# what code I should use for Internet explorer to rotate my image

Tags: html, css

This is code that I am using to rotate a image:

```
 <style>
      #logo1{ position: absolute;
      -moz-animation: 3s rotate infinite linear  ;
      -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%; 
      -webkit-animation: 3s rotate infinite linear  ;
      -webkit-transform-origin:50% 50%;  
      }

    @-moz-keyframes rotate {
        0    { -moz-transform: rotate(0); } 
        100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); }  
        }

    @-webkit-keyframes rotate {
        0%    { -webkit-transform: rotate(0); }
        100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } 
    }
    </style>
```

This code is working fine for firefox, safari and chrome. But its not working for Internet Explorer. What changes I need to do please help....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <style>
    #logo1{ position: absolute;
       animation:3s rotate infinite linear  ;/* IE 10 */
       transform-origin:50% 50%;/* IE 10 */
       -moz-animation: 3s rotate infinite linear  ;
       -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%; 
       -webkit-animation: 3s rotate infinite linear  ;
       -webkit-transform-origin:50% 50%;  
      }

    @-moz-keyframes rotate {
        0    { -moz-transform: rotate(0); } 
        100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); }  
        }

    @-webkit-keyframes rotate {
        0%    { -webkit-transform: rotate(0); }
        100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } 
    }

    @keyframes rotate{
      0    { transform: rotate(0);} /* IE 10 */
      100% { transform: rotate(360deg);} /* IE 10 */
    }

 </style>
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/suhailvs/gHZDb/)

Comment: sorry, but its still not working. Can you give some edit in my code...thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `transform` for IE 10/11, and `-ms-transform` for IE 9.

More compatibility info:  http://caniuse.com/#search=transform

Answer (score 0):

If you need support for older IE add this too:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
```

The rotation property of Internet Explorer’s BasicImage filter can accept one of four values: 0, 1, 2, or 3 which will rotate the element 0, 90, 180 or 270 degrees respectively.